# Flux-async Example: Variable rebinding with $FluxExpectedError

Tags: javascript, flux, immutable.js

I am currently reading the source code for the Flux Async example, which uses Flow and Immutable js libraries:

[Flux-Async Example](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-async/src/records/Todo.js)

The definition of the Todo record is confusing me. The code first declares a Todo class (from Flow doc this seems to be used as an interface, but this file is not placed in the flow/ directory of this example, which is the equivalent of the flow-typed/ directory as explained in the Flow doc). But then, there is a rebinding of the Todo variable and the rebinding is to a new Immutable Record class. I do not understand the purpose of the first class declaration block

```
declare class Todo {
  id: string;
  complete: boolean;
  text: string;

  constructor(data: {
    id: string;
    complete: boolean;
    text: string;
  }): void;

  set(key: 'id', value: string): Todo;
  set(key: 'complete', value: boolean): Todo;
  set(key: 'text', value: string): Todo;
}
```

Can someone please explain this pattern and what its purpose is? Is it safe to assume that this interface is simply there for Flow and nothing more?

Answer (score 0):

In this example app, what you're looking at is indeed Flux's concept of a data model.

You can read a bit about storage and persistence in Flux from these docs:
http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview.html#stores

There's a lot of discussion on Flux's interpretation of Flux vs MVC and bidirectional vs unidirectional - but I assume you've already read that and that's why you're exploring Flux.

Additional reading:

https://codeutopia.net/blog/2016/02/01/react-application-data-flow-where-and-how-to-store-your-data/

Comment: I was curious about the specific syntax of this part of the example code. They declare a class with the name Todo using Flow's `declare` keyword, and then rebind the Todo class to a Immutable.Record class. I don't understand why they declare Todo twice with 2 separate declarations -- why not just have the Immutable.Record class for Todo? Also, why do they use Flow's `declare` keyword in this instance?